# Using split function to extract values in a dataframe by delimiters in python but function giving rows line by line not as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv, split

I have converted an xml file to csv and got this result as a dataframe column "data[column]".

`**0     Jan:2018,000/XXX|Dec:2017,000/XXX|Nov:2017,000...**

**1     Apr:2018,000/XXX|Mar:2018,000/STD|Feb:2018,000...**

**2     Apr:2019,000/XXX|Mar:2019,000/XXX|Feb:2019,000...**

**3                                     Jan:2019,000/XXX|**

**4     Dec:2018,000/XXX|Nov:2018,000/XXX|Oct:2018,000...**

**5     Feb:2019,000/XXX|Jan:2019,000/XXX|Dec:2018,000...**

**6     May:2015,XXX/XXX|Apr:2015,XXX/XXX|Mar:2015,XXX..**.`

i want this dataframe column to get every first value after comma by splitting it by "|".

example:

000,000,000.....

000,000,000...

000,000,000...

000...

000,000,000...

XXX,XXX,XXX...

and store it in dataframe.

i have used this function:

**def my_split(string):**

```
**for x in new.str.split("|"):**

    **for y in x:**

        **print(y.split(",")[-1][0:3])**
```

**new.apply(my_split)**

but i am getting values for every row one after the other.

000

000

000

000

000

000

000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = """0 Jan:2018,000/XXX|Dec:2017,000/XXX|Nov:2017,000...
1 Apr:2018,000/XXX|Mar:2018,000/STD|Feb:2018,000...
2 Apr:2019,000/XXX|Mar:2019,000/XXX|Feb:2019,000...
3 Jan:2019,000/XXX|
4 Dec:2018,000/XXX|Nov:2018,000/XXX|Oct:2018,000...
5 Feb:2019,000/XXX|Jan:2019,000/XXX|Dec:2018,000...
6 May:2015,XXX/XXX|Apr:2015,XXX/XXX|Mar:2015,XXX..."""

df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in s.split('\n')], columns=['col'])
def custom_strip_fnc(m):
    ar = [k.split(',')[1][0:3] for k in m.split('|') if (',') in k]
    return ar# %%
df['splitted'] = df['col'].apply(custom_strip_fnc)
df
```

```
   col  splitted
0   0 Jan:2018,000/XXX|Dec:2017,000/XXX|Nov:2017,0...   [000, 000, 000]
1   1 Apr:2018,000/XXX|Mar:2018,000/STD|Feb:2018,0...   [000, 000, 000]
2   2 Apr:2019,000/XXX|Mar:2019,000/XXX|Feb:2019,0...   [000, 000, 000]
3   3 Jan:2019,000/XXX| [000]
4   4 Dec:2018,000/XXX|Nov:2018,000/XXX|Oct:2018,0...   [000, 000, 000]
5   5 Feb:2019,000/XXX|Jan:2019,000/XXX|Dec:2018,0...   [000, 000, 000]
6   6 May:2015,XXX/XXX|Apr:2015,XXX/XXX|Mar:2015,X...   [XXX, XXX, XXX]
```

Comment: Thanks it was a great help. I know its a lot to ask but can u explain how the loop works in this function. and why my code was not working.

Comment: The `m` parameter in the function runs on each cell, i.e., the initial string you want to split. So `m.split('|')` is a list of string. We iterate through each element in this list as `k,` which is again split with the comma delimiter. As you need only the first three characters after the comma, you get it using `k.split(',')[1][0:3]` of the split value

Comment: Need to get two things from this column. First maximum number of 30+ values per row. example if rows are [000,000,052,023][ 000,000,12,45,6,92] then my output will be 1 for first row and 2 for second row as values are more than 30.